# Macros in GTM: (direct)

Tags: macros, google-tag-manager

What macro type and value do you enter to bucket (direct) traffic?  Thinking constant string with value of utmcsr=(direct)?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Google tag manager is not a tracking tool and does not provide information about the traffic source. If you use "classic" Google analytics you can read the info from the first party utmz cookie (create a new macro, macro type first party cookie with name _utmz, create a rule that checks if the new macro value contains "direct").  However Universal Analytics does no longer store traffic sources in cookies and does not provide a backchannel so you can't get at that information.

Easiest way perhaps would be to use a custom javascript macro that basically checks if document.referrer is set - if there is no referrer information it's (in most cases) a direct visit (a few user agents are set not to send a referrer).